# Replacing with Awk and preserving the FS to OFS

Tags: awk, fs

I have a file with input text below (this is not the original file and just example of input text ) and I want to replace all the 2 letter string to numeric 100 . In this file FS can be :,| or " " (space) , I have no other choice but to treat all three of them as FS, and I want to preserve these field separators at the original position (as in input file)  in the output

```
A:B C|D
AA:C EE G
BB|FF XX1 H
DD:MM:YY K
```

I have tried

```
awk  -F"[:| ]"  '{gsub(/[A-Z]{2}/,"100");print}'
```

but this does not seem to work , please suggest.

Desired output:

```
A:B C|D
100:C 1000 G
100|100 1001 H
100:100:100 K
```

Comment: Use sed instead of awk.

Comment: Can you update a sample output for your input given? What is not working?

Comment: I have update the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functionality in POSIX awk to retain the strings that match the string defined by RS (POSIX) or regexp defined by FS. Since in POSIX RS is just a string there's no need for such functionality and to do it for every FS matching string would be unnecessarily inefficient given it's rarely needed.

With GNU awk where RS can be a regexp, not just a string, you can retain the string that matched the regexp RS with RT but there is no functionality that retains the values that match FS for the same efficiency reason that POSIX doesn't do it. Instead in GNU awk they added a 4th arg to split() so you can retain the strings that match FS in an array yourself if you want it (`seps[]` below):

```
$ awk -v FS='[:| ]' '{
    split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    gsub(/[A-Z]{2}/,"100")
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, seps[i]
    }
    print ""
}' file
A:B C|D
100:C 100 G
100|100 1001 H
100:100:100 K
```

Look up `split()` in [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the answer ,  but when I execute it I get this  awk: fatal: 4 is invalid as number of arguments for split , I guess my version of awk (GNU Awk 3.1.5) does not support 4 arguments to split . Do you know what awk base version supports 4 arguments to split ? and I think [A-Z]{2}  type syntax is also not supported by 3.1.5

Comment: You're welcome. Correct, you are using an archaic version of gawk. The 4th arg to split() has been around since version 4.0 which came out about 5 years ago. You're missing a TON of extremely useful functionality with that old gawk. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History. In your awk RE intervals like `{3}` were disabled by default for backward compatibility with even older pre-POSIX awk versions, add `--re-interval` to enable them. But most importantly - get a new version of gawk!

Answer (score 1):

in this case

```
sed 's/[A-Z]\{2\}/100/g' YourFile
awk '{gsub(/[A-Z]{2}/, "100"); print}' YourFile
```

no need of field separation in this case, change all group of upper letter by "100", unless you specify other constraint than in OP (like other element in the string, you than need to specify what is possible and idealy, add a sample of expected result to be univoq)

Now you certainly have lot more thing around, so this code will certainly failed by changing thing like `ABC:DEF` with `100C:100F` that is certainly not expected

in this case

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]:|]+' '
   {
   split( $0, aS, /[^[:blank:]:|]+/)
   for( i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if( $i ~ /^[A-Z][A-Z]$/) $i = "100"
      printf( "%s%s", $i, aS[i+1])
      }
   printf( "\n" )
   } ' YourFile
```

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between what  you have given as awk solution and my command   awk  -F"[:| ]"  '{gsub(/[A-Z]{2}/,"100");print}'  I am just trying to figure out what is wrong with my command.

Comment: there is one, your field separator is set differently

Answer (score 0):

Give this sed one-liner a try:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/(^|[:| ])[A-Z][A-Z]([:| ]|$)/\1100\2/g' file  
A:B C|D
100:C 100 G
100|FF XX1 H
100:MM:100 K
```

Note:

this will search and replace pattern: **exact two [A-Z] between two delimiters**. If this is not what you want exactly, paste the desired output.

Comment: gnu sed seeing the `-r` and no escape for `()|`. Change maybe `  ` by `[:blank:]` and recursive (2 times seems enough) relacement for accolated group of 2 letter so in final `sed -r 's/(^|[:|[:blank:]])[A-Z][A-Z]([:|[:blank:]]|$)/\1100\2/g;s//\1100\2/g' YourFile `

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine with my Gnu awk:

```
A:B C|D
100:C 100 G     # even the typo in this record got fixed.
100|100 1001 H
100:100:100 K
```

I'd say the problem is that the regex `/[A-Z]{2}/` should be written `/[A-Z][A-Z]/`.